# Stresses in materials depend on co-ordinate system of choice, true or not?

Tags: material-science, solid-mechanics

I was studying stresses and strains and my professor told me that they depend on the co-ordinate system we choose to represent, he also said that as we rotate the co-ordinate system, shears that were primarily not present are introduced and at pi/4 the shear reaches a maximum and then disappears as we further rotate our co-ordinate system. Could anybody explain what it is that he's talking about? A mathematical proof would be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

True, stress is a tensor, an as such it changes when you apply a rotation of coordinates. The transformation of a tensor under a coordinate rotation is equivalent to multiply two matrixes: $T'=RT$, where T is the matrix representing the original tensor, T' the one representing the rotated tensor, and R the matrix of rotation. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) for more details

Comment: Ok. Could you give me some idea of what a Tensor is and why do we need the existence of Tensors, I mean aren't scalars and vectors enough to represent all physical quantities under the universe? Then I'll go down to studying about how rotation affects them

Comment: no, scalars, vectors, and even tensors are not enough. Any object that has a two indexes (and satisfies certain properties) will be a tensor rather than a vector. But check the link to see why stress is a tensor. They have pictures and all that stuff that will be better than my explanation.

Comment: I think you need two rotation matrices.. one is for a vector.